# Plugins for fpdf?

Tags: php, fpdf, html2pdf

I need to draw pdf using fpdf. My pdf content includes html tags. For example if there is image I need to export image in pdf.

Is there any plugin for exporting pdf with html tag accepting functionality.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried this: [Calling FPDF with tablephp plugin](http://fabrikar.com/forums/showthread.php?t=16112). Works well.